# Connection to subfolder of the inbox of a shared mailbox

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

On my laptop it works, however for the team the code works only sometimes. They get below error message.

It is supposed to connect to a specific Outlook folder.

When I reduce code to

```
Set Folder = Ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, olFolderInbox) '//  works fine
```

then there is no issue on their side, however when variable is extended to specific folder it works 1 out of 10 times.

References are set in Excel, folders names are correct because it works on my laptop.

[image]

in line
[image]
`

```vb
Sub macro()

    'declare variable
     Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
     Dim Ns As Outlook.Namespace
     Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
     Dim olShareName As Outlook.Recipient
     Dim olMailItem As Outlook.MailItem

    'clear objects
     Set olApp = Nothing
     Set Ns = Nothing
     Set olShareName = Nothing

    'set outlook variable
     Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
     Set Ns = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
     Set olShareName = Ns.CreateRecipient("xxx@xx.com") /// Owner's email address
    
   
     Set Folder = Ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, olFolderInbox).Folders("SHAREPOINT COO").Folders("COO") '//  doesn't work
     'Set Folder = Ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, olFolderInbox) '//  works fine
     Set Items = Folder.Items
    
end sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set Outlook sub-folders of a shared default folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56938788/how-to-set-outlook-sub-folders-of-a-shared-default-folder)

Answer (score 0):

The error means the folder does not exist. Keep in mind that `Namespace.Folders` returns the top level folders of all stores in the profile. Unless you have a mailbox (not a folder) named "Inbox", that line will fail.

If you want the Inbox folder, use `Namespace.GetDEfaultFolder(olFolderInbox)` instead.

Comment: I see You did not read carefully what I have written.
On my laptop code works fine, folder exists, all of them.
If i'm connecting only to Inbox folder it works on every one laptops.
However if I try to connect to that path Inbox -> Sharepoint COO -> COO then error occurs on other laptops ( on my it works fine, folders exists)

Comment: Then the mailbox with that name ("Inbox") does not exist in the user's active profile. Did you make sure there is a root level folder (mailbox) with that name?

Comment: As I mentioned before - on my laptop code works every time, for others it works 1 out of 10 times.

Comment: Once again, on the problematic machine, did you make sure there is a root level folder (mailbox) with that name?

Comment: yes, there is. Folder inbox is available the same as sub folders.
As I said - when I'm trying to connect to only Inbox it works fine on every machine, but when I trying to reach sub folder in Inbox folder then it works on my machine all the time, on problematic ones sometimes

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Recipient.Resolve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.resolve) method which attempts to resolve a `Recipient` object against the Address Book before calling the [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method.

```
Set olShareName = Ns.CreateRecipient("xxx@xx.com") /// Owner's email address

olShareName.Resolve 

Set Folder = Ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, olFolderInbox)
```

Also I'd recommend breaking the chain of property or method calls by declaring each property or method call on a separate line of code. Thus, you will be able to find out which property or method fails.