# VBA First Project - Shared Outlook Folder Error

Tags: vba, outlook

The code is meant to do the following,

1. Grab each attachment in shared folder
2. Save it to a local drive
3. Move email to a new shared folder.

error occurs on the for i =, this did work previous to adapting to shared files. Also doesn't like the set trash = section. simply says something went wrong.

```
Sub SaveAttachmentsAndMoveEmails()

' Define Outlook objects
Dim MailItemmsg As Object
Dim App As Outlook.Application
Dim Namespace As Outlook.Namespace
Dim Folder As Outlook.Folder
Dim SourceFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim DestFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim MailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim Attachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim i As Long

' Define local drive folder path to save attachments
Dim saveFolderPath As String
saveFolderPath = "H:\Primary Folder\Macro Test"

' Initialize Outlook objects
Set App = New Outlook.Application
Set Namespace = App.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Sharedemail = Namespace.CreateRecipient("abc@email.com")
Sharedemail.Resolve
If Sharedemail.Resolved Then
' Set the source folder where the emails and attachments are located
'Set SourceFolder = Namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Macro")

' Set the destination folder where the emails should be moved to
    Set Inbox = Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(Sharedemail, olFolderInbox)
    Set Trash = Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(Sharedemail, olFolderDeletedItems)
'Set DestFolder = Namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Test")
End If
' Loop through each email in the source folder, Error occurs here
For i = Inbox.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set MailItemmsg = Inbox.Items(i)
    ' Check if the item is an email
    If MailItemmsg.Class = olMail Then
        ' Loop through each attachment in the email
        For Each Attachment In MailItemmsg.Attachments
            ' Save the attachment to the local drive
            Attachment.SaveAsFile saveFolderPath & "\" & Attachment.FileName
        Next
        ' Move the email to the destination folder
        MailItemmsg.Move Trash
    End If
Next i

' Clean up Outlook objects
Set Attachment = Nothing
Set MailItem = Nothing
Set SourceFolder = Nothing
Set DestFolder = Nothing
Set Namespace = Nothing
Set App = Nothing

MsgBox "Attachments saved and emails moved successfully!"

End Sub
```

code above has worked on a non-shared inbox, currently modifying it for a shared folder. Any help is appreciated! Gives Run-time error operation fialed at For i = Inbox.items.Count

Comment: See if this applies https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56938788/how-to-set-outlook-sub-folders-of-a-shared-default-folder

Comment: Hello, I wasn't able to uncheck the cache option. So I decided to alter the code to exclude subfolders all together and now I am getting an error on the iteration portion.

Comment: If `Sharedemail.Resolved` returns False then the following code will fail - you should test for that and Exit when that's the case...

Comment: `Sharedemail.Resolved` is always True for any string in email address format. Outlook VBA documentation demonstrates use on names 
[Recipient.Resolve method (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.resolve) and 
[Recipients.ResolveAll method (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients.resolveall)

Comment: If that's the case then Saredemail.Resolved may be useless as a check. For me I wonder why the For i loop would work perfectly for the default folders but not for a Sharepoint folder.

Comment: To verify the folder use `Inbox.Display`.

Answer (score 0):

Would you try replacing `Namespace` with `Session`.

[Runtime Error with NS.GetSharedDefaultFolder VBA method to access shared drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78001293/runtime-error-with-ns-getshareddefaultfolder-vba-method-to-access-shared-drive)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SaveAttachmentsItemsInFolder()

' Define Outlook objects
Dim oMailItemMsg As Object

Dim oInbox As Folder
Dim oTrash As Folder

Dim oMailItem As MailItem
Dim oAttachment As Attachment

Dim i As Long

' Define local drive folder path to save attachments
Dim saveFolderPath As String
saveFolderPath = "H:\Primary Folder\Macro Test"

' Initialize Outlook objects
Dim sharedEmail As Recipient
Set sharedEmail = Session.CreateRecipient("abc@email.com")

Set oInbox = Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(sharedEmail, olFolderInbox)
Set oTrash = Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(sharedEmail, olFolderDeletedItems)

Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long

' Loop through each email in oInbox
For i = oInbox.Items.count To 1 Step -1

    Set oMailItemMsg = oInbox.Items(i)
    
    ' Check if the item is an email
    If oMailItemMsg.Class = olMail Then
    
        ' Loop through each attachment in the email
        For Each oAttachment In oMailItemMsg.Attachments
            ' Save the attachment to the local drive
            oAttachment.SaveAsFile saveFolderPath & "\" & oAttachment.FileName
            k = k + 1
        Next
        
        ' Move the email to the destination folder
        oMailItemMsg.Move oTrash
        j = j + 1
        
    End If
Next i

MsgBox j & " emails moved ." & vbCr & k & " attachments saved."

End Sub
```