# Runtime Error with NS.GetSharedDefaultFolder VBA method to access shared drive

Tags: vba, outlook, runtime-error

Myself and a colleague both have access to a shared outlook account we'll call "mailbot", I'm writing a VBA macro that scans for emails in the main inbox, extracts information, and uses that to populate an excel sheet.

The following code executes this perfectly on my computer

```
Sub Account_Change()

Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objectNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim sharedmailbox As Outlook.Recipient

Set outlookApp = Outlook.Application
Set objectNS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI") 'Object that can access folders/storage
objectNS.Logon

Set sharedmailbox = objectNS.CreateRecipient("mailbot@mailcarrier.com")

sharedmailbox.Resolve

If sharedmailbox.Resolved Then

    Set objFolder = objectNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(sharedmailbox, olFolderInbox)
    
    For Each Item In objFolder.Items
        If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
            Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem: Set oMail = Item
            body_str = CStr(oMail.Body)
        End If
    Next
End If
```

However on my colleagues pc he gets the error

> Run-time error '-2147221219 (8004011d)': The operation failed because of a registry or installation problem, restart outlook and try again. If the problem persists reinstall

This highlights the line

```
Set objFolder = objectNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(sharedmailbox, olFolderInbox)
```

As being the one causing the error, and restarting outlook does not cause any difference. I added the logon line after checking microsofts documentation on how to setup shared access but this did not fix the issue. Has anyone had experience with this before/know how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment the OP indicated
"This has worked, I had already formatted the resolve the way you note here and it was not working, it seems the labelling of `session.getshareddefaultfolder` was the solution.".

My point remains `Resolve` is for names not addresses.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.resolve
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients.resolveall

---

This frequently asked question is usually due to

```
If sharedmailbox.Resolved Then
```

always being True when an address is used in

```
Set sharedmailbox = Session.CreateRecipient("anyAddressWillResolveIncludingThis@nowhere.com")
```

This demonstrates how to apply `Resolve`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Account_Change()

Dim sharedMailbox As Recipient

Dim objFolder As Folder
Dim objItem As Object

Dim objMail As MailItem

Dim body_str As String

'Set sharedmailbox = Session.CreateRecipient("anyAddressWillResolveIncludingThis@nowhere.com")

Dim mailboxName As String
mailboxName = "mailbox name"

Set sharedMailbox = Session.CreateRecipient(mailboxName)

' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.resolve
' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients.resolveall

sharedMailbox.Resolve   ' Resolve name not address

If sharedMailbox.Resolved Then

    Set objFolder = Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(sharedMailbox, olFolderInbox)
    
    For Each objItem In objFolder.Items
        If TypeOf objItem Is MailItem Then
            Set objMail = objItem
            body_str = CStr(objMail.Body)
        End If
    Next
    
Else

    'When there is an email address error as you generated 
    ' or a mailbox name is not resolved as in the demonstration code,
    ' it is a setup problem.
    MsgBox mailboxName & " not resolved."
    
End If

End Sub
```

The email address is sufficient without `.Resolve`.

When there is an email address error as you generated or a mailbox name is not resolved as in the demonstration code, it is a setup problem.

Comment: In the code you are avoiding the exception, but not solving the problem. So, the OP will just have the `not resolved` message box.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Then the OP can ask at SuperUser.

Comment: This is a programming question not related SuperUser. Your code doesn't solve the issue, just avoids the exception at runtime.

Comment: This has worked, I had already formatted the resolve the way you note here and it was not working, it seems the labelling of session.getshareddefaultfolder was the solution. I'm not sure i understand why currently but thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `GetSharedDefaultFolder` method and the `recipient` (specified as a parameter) is hidden from the global address list such an error can occur.

This can also happen if Outlook is in cached mode and the Outlook Offline Global Address Book is not up to date - either not generated on the server (it's typically generated only daily) or not downloaded by the client.

Also you may try to re-create the mail profile on the problematic machine. If that doesn't help follow the instructions given in the exception message:

> registry or installation problem, restart outlook and try again. If the problem persists reinstall

Answer (score 0):

`0x8004011d` is `MAPI_E_FAILONEPROVIDER` error - it is a generic error that quite a few MAPI methods return when thing go wrong. It is highly unlikely to be registry or installation specific.

Ensure you can access that mailbox in Outlook itself - File | Open & Export | Open Other User's Folder.

Also try to pass the user name rather than SMTP address when calling `CreateRecipient`.